# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting this Exception:org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree
when i excute this below query :

```
<query name="fetchCSpecificationByAttIdExtId">      
 <![CDATA[from
> CProductSpecifications where attributeId=:attributeId  and
> extractedProductId in (:extractedList)]]>     </query>
```

detailed stack trace is:

```
  org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree
   [ from com.bemol.dao.product.CProductSpecifications where attributeId=:attributeId  and extractedProductId in ()
         ]
```

Service method which calls this query is :

```
List<CProductSpecifications> cSpecList=(List<CProductSpecifications>)this.baseDao.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("fetchCSpecificationByAttIdExtId", new String[]{"attributeId","extractedList"},new Object[]{aid,extractedList});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps extractedList is empty? Try to do an empty check first.